# Vue router with Vue 3 raises the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

Created a simple Vue project using the CLI:

```
vue create my-project
```

Wanted to add two pages, so installed the latest version of vue-router (which is currently v3.4.8) and followed the [vue mastery tutorial for routing](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-router-a-tutorial-for-vue-3/).

This is what my router.js file looks like:

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import About from './components/About.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', name: 'About', component: About },
  ]
})

export default router
```

And of course, this is what my main.js file looks like:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router'

createApp({
  template: `
  <div>
    <router-link to='/'>Home</router-link>
    <router-link to='/create'>Create</router-link>
  </div>
  `
})
.use(router)
.mount('#app')
```

Both of the Home and About components don't really have much in them, this is what they look like:

```
<template>
  <div>TODO: Home</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Home'
  }
</script>
```

Anyway, all of this to say that I am getting the following error on:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>
> at eval (router.js?41cb:5)

This is specifically on `createRouter`

Have I done something wrong?

Edit: as Boussadjra Brahim pointed out, originally `createWebHistory` was just being passed in without being a function call. I've since updated the code to include this.

Interestingly enough, once that was done, the error is not happening upon it's call.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This issue is caused when you install Vue router 3 with Vue 3 so you should uninstall the current version :

```
npm uninstall vue-router --save
```

and install the new one by :

```
npm i vue-router@next --save
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-leaf-hkhfz?file=/src/router.js)

Comment: I have a same problem, but this didn't help me :(  Vue version: 3.0.2,  "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0", "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.8"

Comment: could you enrich this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-leaf-hkhfz?file=/src/router.js)? in order to debug it

Comment: Hmm.. there I get some CORS issues? (I just routing within the site). Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-colden-mtti2
 , I added List and Detail

Comment: It doesn't work for me. If you click here any link in "List" page, I get CORS error in FF, or no errors in Chrome, but dead link. In my local system, I have same error as the OP in title of this page. I tried what you suggested, still nothing.

Comment: It work on me. my package.json  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },

Comment: Keep up the good work

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was the other way round (I was getting the same error), I had vue 2.6 installed and Vue Router 4, so I had to downgrade Vue Router to 3.5

Answer (score 3):

For vue3 you should install the `@4` package with the following command:

```
npm install vue-router@4
```

Please consult the following migration guide if you're having problems: [Migrating from Vue 2](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/)