# How to add Router to @vue/cli app with vuejs 3?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-cli

Learning vuejs3 I created new @vue/cli app with command

```
vue create myapp
```

with vuejs 3 selected
I added Router to my project and added Router reference in my src/main.js :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import { createRouter/*, createWebHistory */ } from 'vue-router'
import WelcomeScreen from './pages/WelcomeScreen.vue'
import UsersList from './pages/UsersList.vue'

import App from './App.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  // history: createWebHistory(),
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: WelcomeScreen },
    { path: '/users', component: UsersList }
  ]
})
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

But In the console I see warning :

```
"export 'createRouter' was not found in 'vue-router'
```

and error :

```
main.js?56d7:10 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

In my package.json I have :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "mitt": "^2.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.8"
  },
```

and

```
$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.8
```

Which way is valid?
Also are some some vuejs3 tutorials for @vue/cli?
I found some vuejs 3 tutorials, but not for @vue/cli and that raise some confusion...

Say in my @vue/cli with vue2 I use file src/router/index.js, but I do not remember if
I have created manually...

Thanks!

Comment: does this help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64576169/8172857 ?

Comment: Please add vue-router with version  "vue-router": "^4.0.0-beta.13"
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router/v/4.0.0-beta.13

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need install vue-router like this for ***vue3***:

```
npm install vue-router@next --save
```

Router.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
    import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router"
    const routeInfos = [
        {
            path : "/",
            component : HomePage
        },
        {
            path : "/favorites",
            component : FavoritesPage
        }
    ]
    
    const router = createRouter({
        history : createWebHistory(),
        routes : routeInfos
    })
    
    export default router;
```

import In Main.js

```
import router from "./router"
createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Hi.i think you should check this blog again. https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-router-a-tutorial-for-vue-3/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](https://programmerah.com/solved-vue3-error-export-createrouter-was-not-found-in-vue-router-35877/)

// uninstall vue2.x vue-router

```
npm uninstall vue-router --save
```

// install vue3 vue-router

```
npm install vue-router@next --save
```