# Vue JS 3, use vue-router 3 instead of 4?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I'm trying to use vue-router 3 instead of vue-router 4 in Vue JS 3.
It is possible?

Using `@3` instead `@next` I have the same problem as here:

[Vue3 "export 'createWebHistory, createRouter' was not found in 'vue-router'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723642/vue3-export-createwebhistory-createrouter-was-not-found-in-vue-router/70738849#70738849)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you do that? They built v4 for Vue3:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next

Version 3 was for Vue2.

The features should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation I was trying to fall back to an older version was because I found in a tutorial a very difficult way to use for '*'. A lot of lines of code and regex complexity.
Believed that using that way isn't easy and natural. I'm a backend dev and in Python Flask it somehow easier and clear like in Vue JS 2

After digging and digging and digging (I don't understand why the show more complicated way like "router.resolve", etc) I found the this way

```
{ path: "/:catchAll(.*)", redirect:"/" } .
```

As a side note as a new Vue JS developer I just found that there are more functions to catch paths:

**catchAll, pathMatch, noPage
(I will study to understand the difference).**

The page that enlighted me was: [Vue Router - catch all wildcard not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526486/vue-router-catch-all-wildcard-not-working)